# How can I show sequential comment as elapsed time goes by?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's showing sequential messages as elapsed time goes by.
But my code works only for HTML5 video player.

If I would like to do the same thing with jwplayer, how can I fix my javascript??

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var comments = [{'time':'5','message':'hello! 5 secs has past'},{'time':'10','message':'hello! 10 secs has past'},{'time':'30','message':'hello! 30 secs has past'}];

    $('#video').on('timeupdate',function(e){
        showComments(this.currentTime);
    });

    function showComments(time){
        var comments = findComments(time);
        $.each(comments,function(i,comment){
            $('p').text(comment.message);
            $('p').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
        });
    }

    function findComments(time){
        return $.grep(comments, function(item){
          return item.time == time.toFixed();
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML with html5 video player**

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media"><source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

**HTML with jwplayer**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4",
        title: "test",
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        autostart: true,
        autoplay: true,
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It appears jwplayer uses an api method called `onTime(callback)` to handle updates while playing.. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/

Comment: @veritasetratio thanks! why his answer worn't work though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not calling the showCommetns method in case of `jwplayer`, you need to use the `onTime(callbak)` option to do that - [Doc](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/)

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#video').on('timeupdate',function(e){
        showComments(this.currentTime);
    });   
});

var comments = [{'time':'5','message':'hello! 5 secs has past'},{'time':'10','message':'hello! 10 secs has past'},{'time':'30','message':'hello! 30 secs has past'}];
function showComments(time){
    var comments = findComments(time);
    $.each(comments,function(i,comment){
        $('p').text(comment.message);
        $('p').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
    });
}

function findComments(time){
    return $.grep(comments, function(item){
        return item.time == time.toFixed();
    });
}

jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4",
    title: "test",
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    autostart: true,
    autoplay: true
});

jwplayer("myElement").onTime(function(time){
    console.log('time:' + time)
    showComments(Math.round(time.duration));
})
```

Note: The method `showComments` and dependencies are moved to global scope since it needs to be access outside the closure scope by `jwplayer` configuration